# TFS 2010 checkin with tf.exe command-line

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have several projects in my TFS collection and I want to perform checkin during build of one of the project. I have build template and I'd like to use tf.exe with InvokeProcess activity. But how can I specify source files and destination project folder in command-line arguments of tf.exe? Or I need copy files manually to destination project folder?

Comment: How did you check out the files? Did you, for example, check out in a different workspace than the one used during build / as a different user?

Comment: I didn't check out the files. Is it possible to check in something without check out?

Comment: It is possible to add to source control new items. But if a source module exists, you need to first check out in order to check in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the **WorkingDirectory** property of the **InvokeProcess** Activity to the folder where your Workspace on the server is. You may need to the **ConvertWorkspaceItem**(s) Activity to convert it to a physical path on the server (i.e. C:\Code from $/Server/Code). If you've not done this before, you may need to create a Sequence activity to perform the 2 steps; you can then store the output of ConvertWorkspaceItem in a variable scoped to the Sequence, and use it as the WorkingDirectory of the InvokeProcess.

Comment: As I understood, first I need to check out old files, then copy new files to physical path on the server, and then call tf.exe checkin with path to that file? Is that correct?